# No module named 'pyhive'

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, ipython, pyhive

I'm trying to access data from Hive in a iPython Notebook.
So I run

```
pip3 install PyHive
```

This returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyHive in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

But then when I run the following import

```
from pyhive import hive
```

I get the following error message

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-747088b97eb4> in <module>()
----> 1 from pyhive import hive

ImportError: No module named 'pyhive'
```

Why can't I access pyhive when it's already installed.

Comment: Where is your python installed? is it in /usr/local/? You may be running another python from another distribution.

Comment: In your notebook, what's the value of `sys.executable`?

Comment: Yup that's not the path to the python I'm using. How do I change the sys.executable to point to the system Python 3. It's currently pointing to /Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: I am having this exact problem.  I am not seeing a great solution anywhere. Was anyone able to fin a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have multiple instances of python installed on your computer. In order to change environments from one instance to another, you will need to activate the environment. If you're using conda, you can use the command

```
conda env list
```

which will list all of your installed environments. You can use a particular environment with

```
activate py2
```

"py2" is an example name, insert your own environment name. From there, you can find whether that particular instance has a PyHive installed with

```
pip list
```

if not, install it with pip or pip3.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Steltron in that there may be multiple python instances. If you don't have Anaconda (or even if you do), here is the general way to diagnose and fix the issue.

You can check the version of your default python interpreter with

```
python --version
```

If it is not python3 (likely python2), you can do a few things to correct it. I've listed two possible solutions below:

1. Install PyHive for python2 if it is available.
2. Add the python3 directory to your `PYTHONPATH` in your `.bashrc` or `profile` file in the home directory. Then, activate python3 in the command line with some variant of `source activate python3`.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

> pip install pyhive

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still having the problem, I went to my python packages folder and found that PyHive was not there. so my solution was to install via pip straight from their official github directory. Follow the command:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive.git
```

or

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive.git
```